# How can I scroll page to show an error message?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have been using Yii for the last two months. How can I scroll a page to show an error message in Yii? I am using the bootstrap widget

```
widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert');
```

Comment: assign id to that, and in case of error go to #alertID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate the Alert with specific ID

```
<?php
Yii::app()->user->setFlash(TbHtml::ALERT_COLOR_WARNING,'<strong>Warning!</strong> This is your warning.');
?>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert',array('htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'MyAlert'))); ?>
```

Now, use bellow jQuery statement according to your functionality

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ValidateForm").click(function(){
        //on errors 
        $("#MyAlert").get(0).scrollIntoView();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Ye i am undrstnd tinyByte wrote this upper. Thanks for grammar edit. I am from Ukraine, me just 18 and i dont have practice in English, but i am very want it.